# Tensorflow GPU model failing to train on custom images

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection

i have recently been playing around with tensorflow object detection with GPU processor, and i have encountered an error when trying to train my model with custom images.The error tracestack is as follows:

```
 WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\trainer.py:260: create_global_step (from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.train.create_global_step
WARNING:tensorflow:num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 184, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "train.py", line 180, in main
    graph_hook_fn=graph_rewriter_fn)
  File "C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\trainer.py", line 274, in train
    train_config.prefetch_queue_capacity, data_augmentation_options)
  File "C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\trainer.py", line 80, in create_input_queue
    include_keypoints=include_keypoints))
  File "C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\core\preprocessor.py", line 3147, in preprocess
    (func.__name__))
ValueError: The function random_horizontal_flip does not exist in func_arg_map
```

I am using an Anaconda interpreter with Python 3.6, tio reproduce this error i followed all the steps in the link https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10 .

The command which gave me this error was:

```
python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config
```

it is important to note i did not encounter any issues before training the model. I would be greatfull if someone could explain this error to me and even help me fix it, thanks in advance :-)

Comment: were you able to resolve it? and how? I'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You might forget to add the below line to `~/.bashrc`:
`export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim`